# Removing multiple external api call in search box autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I am working on an app written in Python Django. There is a page containing a search box that accepts text input from the user and when the input length is greater than or equal to 2, it does an ajax call to an external API. 
So for example, say if I type `'ka'`, it will do an ajax call to that API with the parameter `'ka'` and return 20 strings with that prefix. Again, if I type `'kar'`, it will again do an ajax call with `'kar'` and return 20 strings with the prefix `'kar'`.

The API that I am calling can return all the strings with the prefix if I don't specify the number of matches I want. So I want the response of the first ajax call to be saved somewhere so that on successive key press with same prefix, no more ajax call will be done to that external API.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think is possible out of the box, but you could easily implement it yourself using http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source .

You could supply your own function as a source, which would do the AJAX request only if it doesn't have response cached from one of previous requests.

Comment: But I don't think only caching would help because for different prefix different set of strings will appear, like when I type 'kar' it should not give me any string with prefix 'kab' in autosuggest drop down. If I am wrong, please rectify.

Comment: you could cache all responses to the 'ka' and than when you search for 'kar' do a loop through the cache and pick only things starting with 'kar'. If you ran into troubles with speed, I believe you could use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie to speed it up quite a bit. But if you under let's say few hundreds for 'ka', it should be fast enough. You could cache by first letter and than loop through the rest... but if you want top speed, trie would be your pick